# Android.Net.Wifi.P2p in Xamarin Monodroid?

Tags: wifi, xamarin.android, p2p, xamarin

Does android.net.wifi.p2p planned to include to xamarin monodroid?
It does exist in documentstion:

http://docs.monodroid.net/?link=N%3aAndroid.Net.Wifi.P2p

But I can't see it in Mono.Android.dll (v2.0.50727)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a sample for WiFiDirect using Xamarin, here it is https://github.com/Cheesebaron/WiFiDirectSample

This is a basic sample of invoking and finding WiFiDirect devices around. Hope that helps you get started.

Comment: Rather than just providing a link, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and just provide the link for additional reference. If you're not up to this task, you should consider simply [leaving a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) on the question instead of posting an answer, which you'll be able to do with a bit more reputation.

Answer (score 0):

The Android.Net.Wifi.P2p namespace was added in API level 14 (see the [corresponding Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/package-summary.html)).

If you set your app to target Android 4.0 or higher, you will be able to access this namespace.

Comment: I know it. But in I don't know if MonoDroid can do it.
Sure I can set it in Eclipse, but I'm using Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, Mono for Android does support it. In your project properties you need to target at least Android 4.0 in order to use that.